# what is that strange site?

Tags: discussion

can anyone explain how it comes that this site mirrors stackoverflow somehow?

https://software-testing.com/topic/217764/bootloop-issue-and-can-t-go-to-recovery-mode/2

[Bootloop issue and can't go to recovery mode](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/224131/bootloop-issue-and-cant-go-to-recovery-mode)

Comment: @AndrewT. so it's legit? the fact that they use fake users and date is disturbing, and content is incomplete/misleading sometimes

Comment: Not sure what "legit" means here, but it's common for them to also change any non-important meta info. However, since you're also the answerer of that Q, you *might* try to follow the methods described in the main meta post, if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is known as [scraper](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/200177/241919). Basically, they copy the content from Stack Exchange Q&A. By its nature, since every post here is licensed as CC BY-SA, it's permitted to distribute the content elsewhere, *provided with required attribution*.

Unfortunately, not many sites fulfill the requirement, and usually, there's nothing you can do (unless you are *the owner of the post*).

> **The site doesn't follow attribution requirements, uses a different license, or claims ownership of the content.** Unfortunately, at this time, there is no action we (Stack Exchange) can take as we do not own the content ourselves, and reports regarding such content are no longer accepted or actioned. You may, however, be able to take action yourself if you are the owner of the content.

You can read the post on the main meta for more information.

Comment: "there's nothing you can do" – I disagree. You can go to the [contact page at Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact), and report it choosing "Stack Exchange content is being reproduced without attribution", fill in the links (original and copy-cat), add some additional notes if you have any, and send it. That makes the SE legal team aware of the issue – and they have quite different means of dealing with it than we simple users have ;)

Comment: PS: I've just reported it over at Meta.SE.

Comment: @Izzy actually, that suggestion is already outdated [since Oct 2021](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/200178/27) when SE staff updated the FAQ that they are not interested in receiving the reports that come from Contact Us anymore.

Comment: Thanks Andrew! I wasn't aware of that change as I haven't reported any site recently. Should be linked then from that contact page (you cannot expect users having read all the existing stuff before). And there I wondered about the strange auto-reply I got which looked so different from what they sent in the past…